# Javascript /Jquery Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, blogger

I have a slider on my blog that won't work once the page is cached. The slider is only visible on the home page so I want to reload just this page and not take away cache functionality from other pages. Can I enter an argument into javascript to get the home page to load from server every time? or?

Thanks!
KIN

UPDATE

Still working on this. I have noticed that the error I get when the slider dose not load is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bxSlider' page2.html:1175
(anonymous function) page2.html:1175
k jquery.min.js:2
l.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
p.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
D
```

Here is the code I am using.

```
<head>
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js'/>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src='https://googledrive.com/host/0B4lBcpVXd4Y-c2kyZWF5QWpxME0' type='text/javascript'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(&#39;.bxslider&#39;).bxSlider();
});
</script></head>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post some example code and also define 'slider'. The cache should have nothing to do with the functioning of a 'normal' js slider.

Answer (score 1):

The cache shouldn't have anything to do w/ the slider, but to answer your question, use location.reload(true). Documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp
The true argument forces the page to reload from server.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I tried the location.reload(true) but I don't think I am implementing it correctly. Here is my blog.http://peterkindelberg.blogspot.com/

Comment: Please see my updated problem above. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the object you are selecting with &#39;.bxslider&#39; is not what you think you're selecting. I'm unfamiliar with that syntax- what attributes have you set on the object you are trying to select? What does calling bxSlider do?

Comment: It should call the bx slider, and it does when I refresh the page but if I click on any other page and click on the homepage again it breaks.

Comment: Had no luck with this, I think somehow my jQuery is clashing. Moving on to pure JavaScript slider...